# Python script to obtain status of files/folders

Tags: library, file-management, python

Is there a Python-based library/script that can check the last date at which a list of file/folders was modified and create a Markdown document out of that?

The use case is that I regularly back up a few folders, and I want to have a status page which I can store on GitHub and others can view to have an idea of when a folder was last backedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
import os
import datetime

directory = raw_input('Enter a directory address: \n')
foldercheck = raw_input("Do you want to print folder contents also? Y/N ?\n")
log = open ("log.txt", "w")
def listing(strn):
for f in os.listdir(strn) :

    #print (f, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f)))
    pathname = os.path.join(strn, f)
    prevpathname = (strn)
    os.chdir(strn)
    if (os.path.isfile(pathname)):    
        log.write (str(pathname) + "\t last modified:\t" + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(pathname))) + "\n")
    if(foldercheck == "Y"):
        if(os.path.isdir(pathname)):
            log.write(str(pathname) +  "\tlast modified:\t" + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(pathname))) + "\n")
    if(os.path.isdir(pathname)) :
        #print("current path:\n"+ pathname)
        os.chdir(pathname)
        listing(pathname)
        #print("changing path back to:\n"+ prevpathname)
        os.chdir(prevpathname)

listing(directory)
```

> as far as markdown you can edit the log.write file in markdown syntax
>   and instead of saving it as .txt use .m

checked on win10 python 2.7.11
Hope it helps

Comment: Afraid this doesn't meet the requirements fully: 1) no markdown, 2) incomplete (OP writes about "a few folders" – and thus obviously wants a script that covers them all). The basic idea might fit – but for an answer, it needs some enhancement :)

Comment: markdown part user can edit it himself the way he wants and for the complete list of files along with folders i have updated the complete code.
checked on windows 10